# .NET Core options binding with JSON files: inconsistent behavior with invalid collection items

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have detected an inconsistent and annoying behavior with .NET Core options binding when JSON files come into play.

The target framework is *.NET Core 2.2*.

Let's use the following JSON file:

```json
{
  "Category": "Bravo",
  "SubOptionsAsArray": [
    {
      "Category": "Bravo"
    },
    {
      "Category": "Zulu"
    }
  ],
  "SubOptionsAsList": [
    {
      "Category": "Bravo"
    },
    {
      "Category": "Zulu"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm using a property named `Category` on different levels. This property can take the values `Alpha` and `Bravo`. Value `Zulu` is considered invalid.

Here is the C# code to read the JSON file and add it to a service provider:

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

namespace Example
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("example.json")
        .Build();

      var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
        .Configure<MyOptions>(configuration)
        .BuildServiceProvider();

      var options = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<MyOptions>>().Value;
    }
  }

  public class MyOptions
  {
    public MySubOptions[] SubOptionsAsArray { get; set; }

    public List<MySubOptions> SubOptionsAsList { get; set; }

    public MyCategory Category { get; set; }
  }

  public class MySubOptions
  {
    public MyCategory Category { get; set; }
  }

  public enum MyCategory
  {
    Alpha,
    Bravo
  }
}
```

Now let's examine the `options` variable:

`options.SubOptionsAsArray.Length` is 2. The first element is the correctly bound element with category *Bravo*, but the second element is *null*.

`options.SubOptionsAsList.Count` is 1. The first element is the correctly bound element with category *Bravo*. The second element with invalid category *Zulu* has simply been dropped.

IAW: Throwing the options back into a JSON file would look like this:

```json
{
  "Category": "Bravo",
  "SubOptionsAsArray": [
    {
      "Category": "Bravo"
    },
    null
  ],
  "SubOptionsAsList": [
    {
      "Category": "Bravo"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is really annoying since I don't get any information on the invalid data.

When I write JSON like this,...

```json
{
  "Category": "Zulu"
}
```

... the framework throws an exception indicating that *Category* value *Zulu* cannot be bound. **This is the correct behavior I would expect, but not silently dropping invalid data or replacing it with *null*.**

Am I missing something? Or is there a workaround?

Otherwise I consider this a bug and would go forward to open an issue at Github.

---

**EDIT**

I've filed an issue at [Github](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/issues/2357).

Comment: Based on your `MyCategory` enum in the example there is no `Zulu` to bind to.

Comment: When I assign `Zulu` to my top-level `Category`, the framework throws an exception to indicate the invalid property - this is the expected behavior. But if the `Category` is set to an invalid value in nested parts of the structure, the nested parts (here an array/list elemet) are either dropped or set to `null`. This behavior is inconsistent.

Comment: There's no JSON parsing code in the question. Are you asking about *configuration* ? That's completely different and I'd bet that if you tried to access the value by its path (`SubOptionsAsArray:0:Category`), you'd get it. It's *binding the objects to the configuration values* that decides to ignore values that can't be parsed

Comment: It dropping invalid data is by design. If you are looking to validate your options then check docs here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.2#options-validation-1

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, I'm talking about configuation. No, I simply use the posted code, i.e. I'm accessing the `options` variable in the `Main` method.

Comment: When you call `AddJson` the Configuration system will parse the JSON data, flatten it and store it in a flat key/value store. That's [described in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.2). The same happens for *every* other config source, eg INI files, databases, whatever. That's what allows using multiple sources and overriding previous values. When you ask for an object , it's bound to those properties by type/property name.

Comment: @Nkosi That's not quite correct. Invalid data leads to an exception. Try it by setting the top-level `Category` to an invalid value, e.g. `Zulu`. You'll discover an exceptions.

Comment: Binding objects to configuration keys has nothing to do with JSON serialization, it happens at least one level above that step. It *can* be controlled, allowing far more rigorous validations than simply checking the type, eg checking value ranges, setting combinations, the *existence* of a database etc

Comment: @PeterPerot I was referring to the array/collections. But I see what you are referring to. understood

Comment: @PeterPerot exceptions when doing what? Loading the JSON configuration or deserializing using JSON.NET? Besides, changing the *key* of a config property is different from changing its value

Comment: @PeterPerot believe there may be some confusion about how the configuration loads/parses the data and how it binds to object graphs.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm not talking about JSON serialization. It's all about the _Configuration_ stuff of .NET Core. Use the small JSON file `{ "Category": "Zulu" }` and run my code. The line `serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<MyOptions>>().Value` then throws an exception: `System.InvalidOperationException: 'Failed to convert 'Zulu' to type 'Example.MyCategory'.'` I would exception the behavior to be the same for the nested objects.

Comment: I think the other issue here is that config binding has different behavior for `Array` and `List` when there's an exception and it worth filing an issue on the github repo

Comment: @Kahbazi Exactly! And since the **invalid nested elements are dropped**, there is no indication of an invalid config file.

Comment: @PeterPerot Have you issue this on github repo? if not I can handle it

Comment: @Kahbazi Thanks for your offer of help. I've just filed an issue here: https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/issues/2357